# Passing SDL_Window to another class

Tags: c++, sdl

I am trying to pass SLD_Window *window to another class to work on it.
I don't know if it is a proper way of programming, but I would like to try that.
I am creating a SDL_Window *Window in main.cpp and then passing the pointer *Window to another class. 
I found out that all Renderer functions doesn't have any impact in window, but when I copied them to window.cpp screen was red.
Looks like I pass the pointer but it creates completly new window.
How can I work in many classes on same window which is defined in main class?
It is like this because I would like to build a Draw.cpp where I would keep all drawing functions.

main.cpp

```
SDL_Window *WindowMain = NULL;
window Window(WindowMain , name);
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(WindowMain , -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 100);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer)
```

window.h

```
    class window {
public:
    window(SDL_Window *Window, const char* Nazwa );
    virtual ~window();
private:
    SDL_Window *okno;
};
```

window.cpp

```
window::window(SDL_Window *Window, const char* Nazwa) {
    okno = Window;
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) !=0)
    {
        printf("Unable to initialize SDL due error: %s", SDL_GetError());
    }
    okno =  SDL_CreateWindow(Nazwa,
                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, // X position
                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, // Y position
                    800,    // Width
                    600,    // Height
                    SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(okno == NULL){
        printf("Unable to create window due error: %s", SDL_GetError());
    }
}

window::~window() {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(okno);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: you've violating all type/variables naming conventions. Difficult to read...

Comment: The problem is that you're expecting the window pointed to by the `Window` parameter to change, but you don't actually do anything with it. You apparently have an `okno` field in your `window` class, but setting that field to some other value won't change the `okno` you declared in `main`.

You should probably brush up on some basic C++ knowledge before writing a full application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main routine declares `okno` locally:

```
SDL_Window *okno = NULL;
window Window(okno, name);   // `okno` is NULL and remains NULL
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(okno, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
```

in window.cpp you're using a member called `okno`, a global, whatever, but that cannot be the same variable.

```
window::window(SDL_Window *Window, const char* Nazwa) {
    okno = Window;
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) !=0)
    {
        printf("Unable to initialize SDL due error: %s", SDL_GetError());
    }
    okno =  SDL_CreateWindow(Nazwa,
```

both `okno` variables have a total different scope and you cannot initialize `okno` from the `window` constructor like this.

=> `okno` remains `NULL` at main level => your `SDL_CreateRenderer` is passed a NULL window pointer.

(Not to mention the design is really wierd,so is the naming...)

What you probably want is:

```
window Window(name);
SDL_Window *okno = Window.okno;
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(okno, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
```